# How to update scatter marker color in an animation with set_offsets

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to create an animation that plots GPS data from a run. I have code that plots the points and creates the animation. In order to have the old point deleted and the new plotted with each frame I am using `scat.set_offsets(x[i],y[i])` to plot the points. The trouble I am running into is that I want the color of the point to reflect the speed at that position. The code below works but I cannot figure out the color updating. I have tried using `scat.alpha()` but it switches the color once and never updates again. I want to use, jet, for example, and have 0 mph be blue and the fastest time to be red.

The running log has the first two columns as `lon/lat` and the third is `velocity`. Some data:

```
 Longitude   Latitude   GPS Speed(km/h)

-88.19895578    43.19975045 0

-88.19894667    43.19976286 0

-88.19893236    43.19977277 0

-88.19872605    43.19969481 9.9

-88.19871956    43.19967161 10.799999

-88.19872339    43.19962663 11.7

-88.19873801    43.19959561 11.7

-88.19879232    43.19958254 9.9

-88.19876674    43.1995382  9.9

-88.19876797    43.19948614 7.2
```

The code is below. Thanks for the help!

```
"""
Matplotlib Animation of Accelerometer Vectors

author: Ryan Croke
website: http://TheHolyMath.com
"""

import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib  import cm
import csv
import json
import smopy
import re

### DATA ###
# Read shape file
g = nx.read_shp("tl_2014_us_state/tl_2014_us_state.shp")

# plot points of acceleration and deceleration
f = open('runninglog.csv')
cr = csv.reader(f)

# Make arrays for processing
latitude = []
longitude = []
velocity = []

# Velocity is in m/s - convert to miles/hour
# 1m/s = 2.236 mph
for row in cr:
    # Need to test for headers - pass anything with letters
    if any(c.isalpha() for c in row[0]) == True:
        pass
    else:
        longitude.append(float(row[0]))

    if any(c.isalpha() for c in row[1]) == True:
        pass
    else:
        latitude.append(float(row[1]))

    if any(c.isalpha() for c in row[2]) == True:
        pass
    else:
        velocity.append(round(float(row[2])*2.236,2))

# Numer of plots
P = int(len(latitude))

# In the USA longitude is decreasing from west to east, latitude is increasing from south to north
# lower left will be max(lon) and min(lat)
pos1 = (float(min(latitude)),float(max(longitude)))
pos2 = (float(max(latitude)),float(min(longitude)))

### Animation ###
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
map = smopy.Map(pos1, pos2, z=15)
# Smoopy allows you to create a matplotlib image using a t0_pixels command
x = []
y = []

# Create array's for lat/lon in pixel image
for i in xrange(len(latitude)):
    x1, y1 = map.to_pixels(latitude[i],longitude[i])
    x.append(x1)
    y.append(y1)

# animation of a scatter plot using x, y from above
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fig = plt.figure()
ax = map.show_mpl(figsize=(8, 6))
scat = ax.scatter([],[],s=60)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    scat.set_offsets([])
    #scat.set_facecolor([])
    return scat,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    scat.set_offsets([x[i], y[i]])
    #scat.set_edgecolors('red')
    #scat.set_facecolor()

    return scat,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=P, interval=40, repeat=False, blit=True)

# save the animation as an mp4.  This requires ffmpeg or mencoder to be
# installed.  The extra_args ensure that the x264 codec is used, so that
# the video can be embedded in html5.  You may need to adjust this for
# your system: for more information, see
# http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/animation_api.html
anim.save('Around_the_block_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: `sc.set_array`.  The method is inherited from `ScalerMappable`.  Also, [do not use jet](https://youtu.be/xAoljeRJ3lU)